# How can I get IDE to suggest function parameters of babel compiled javascript?

Tags: javascript, intellisense, babeljs, code-completion

I'm working on a library where I write code in `es6` and transpile it down to `es5`. When trying to test the output `es5` code, the IDE is not able to give me hints of function arguments. It only seems to know that I have exported a function named `foo`. I have tried this on both `vs code` and `Webstorm`. I have seen that many other libraries I have used give hints of function parameters. I have exported functions provided by my library on my library entry file - `index.js`. The entry file looks like this:

```
import {
  foo,
} from "./utils";

export {
  foo
};
```

The output looks like this:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "foo", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _calculate.default;
  }
});

var _calculate = _interopRequireDefault(require("./calculate"));

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

I use babel to transpile like this:

`$ babel -d lib src/`

What can I do to get the transpiled code to provide the user with parameter hints?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using NetBeans IDE you can use L_CTRL+SPACE.. This will open what is available with the libraries you are using. Let's say I use THREE.js; I can type:

THREE.B`L_CTRL+SPACE` and would return this
[image]

Also if you want to provide documentation about a function you can use JavaDoc Coments like this:

```
 /**
  * Author : prisoner849
  * https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/8hqy99jj/
  * @param {type} geometry
  * @param {type} independent
  * @returns {GridBoxGeometry.newGeometry|THREE.BoxBufferGeometry}
  */
  function GridBoxGeometry(geometry, independent) {
     ....
  }
```

[image]